How can to find to infinite series ? $\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{1!}\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{x+3}+...+\infty$
How can I continue to find a solution to infinite series ?  $\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{1!}\cdot\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\cdot\frac{1}{x+3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\infty$
we have
$$S(x)=\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{1!}\cdot\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\cdot\frac{1}{x+3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\infty=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(x+n)}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int^1_0y^{x+n-1}dy=\int^1_0y^{x-1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-y)^n}{n!}dy=\int^1_0y^{x-1}e^{-y} dy$$
therefore:
$$S(x)=\int^1_0y^{x-1}e^{-y}dy$$
and we have
$$\Gamma(x)=\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
then :
$$S(x)=\Gamma(x)-\int^{\infty}_1y^{x-1}e^{-y}dy$$
How can I continue to find a solution?I found this problem in a bookSUMMATION OF SERIES COLLECTED BY L. B. W. JOLLEY, M.A. (cantab.), M.I.E.E. page 18 proplem 93
The solution is presented in the book as:$$S(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

Please, do not write $+\infty$. Every time you do that a puppy dies.

The last integral on your first chain of equalities is the lower incomplete gamma function with parameters $x$ and $1$, that is, $\gamma(x,1)$.

Apparently there's something wrong. If you put in $x=1$, you get $1-e^{-1}$ for the series in the title, but $e-1$ for the series in the end.  I checked the book, I think the series in your title should be multiplied by $e$.

There is a simple way to prove it: Starting from the last expression, express every term in terms of $\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{1}{x+1}$, $\dots$. The first term gives $\frac{1}{x}$, the second one gives $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}$, the third one gives $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+2}$. As you add more terms, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x+k}$ converge to $\frac{e(-1)^k}{k!}$. Nothing fancy here. But of course, there may be simpler solutions with calculus.

You can see the series expansion you are after here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Holomorphic_extension with $s=x$ and $x=1$ (which contains the missing $e^{-1}$ factor).

Since you are adding $\infty$ to the series you'll get $\infty$.

As someone said in the comments the small epsilon $\epsilon$ in the book is the Euler's number $e^1$.
So, you have:
$$ S = e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)n!}$$
Now if you define the rising factorial with the following product:
$$ (x)_{n} = x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n-1) $$
Then
$$ (x+n) (x)_{n} = x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n-1)(x+n) = x(x+1)_n$$
Hence
$$ x+n = \frac{x(x+1)_n}{(x)_n}$$
$$ S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x)_n}{x(x+1)_n}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{e}{x}M(x,x+1,-1) = \frac{e}{x}{}_1F_{1}(x,x+1,-1) $$
where $M$ is the confluent hypergeometric function.
This function allows the Kummer's trasnformation:
$$ M(a,b,z) = e^z\,M(b-a,b,-z)$$
Hence
$$ \boxed{S = \frac{e}{x}M(x,x+1,-1) = \frac{1}{x}M(1,x+1,1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(x+1)_{n}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x)_{n+1}}= \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x(x+1)} +... } $$

$$S(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n! (n+x)}=\Gamma (x,0,1)$$ which  is the generalized incomplete gamma function.
You can write it as
$$S(x)=\Gamma(x,0)-\Gamma(x,1)$$
Expanded as series around $x=0$ involves the unpleasant Meijer G-function.
It is much nicer expanded for large values of $x$ (have a look at $dlmf$).
Starting at $x=1$
$$S(x)=(x-1)!-\frac {a(x)} e $$ where the $a(x)$ form sequence $A000522$ in $OEIS$. Their e.g.f is $\frac{e^x}{1-x}$.
You will find a lot of information in the $OEIS$ page includinf the nice
$$a(x)=\text{Round}[e x!]$$
